# Railroad Diagrams don't show expression names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

Using `pyparsing` version `3.0.0a2` to generate some railroad diagrams I end up with sub-diagrams named Group or Unnamed 1, 2, etc. No need to says that several different expressions have the name `Group`. How can we specify the wanted names for each expression?

[image]

Comment: Best to review the current issues on the pyparsing github repo (https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/issues), and open a new one there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that you are calling `setName` on the significant expressions within your grammar.

This expression will show up as Unnamed:

```
# US social security numbers are of the form 000-00-0000
ssn = Word(nums, exact=3) + '-' + Word(nums, exact=2) + '-' + Word(nums, exact=4)
```

[image: unnamed ssn railroad diagram]

`setName` attaches a name to the expression:

```
ssn = (Word(nums, exact=3) 
       + '-' + Word(nums, exact=2) 
       + '-' + Word(nums, exact=4)).setName("social_security_number")
```

[image: named ssn railroad diagram]

Keep in mind the distinction between `setName` and `setResultsName`:

- `setName` attaches a name to the expression itself (a concept made more
  clear now with the railroad diagram support)
- `setResultsName` designates a name to be attached to the parsed results
  extracted by this expression

An expression will have just one name, such as `Word(nums)` is an "integer". But that expression may be used in several places within a grammar, and so could have multiple results names. See how `real` is used multiple times in this example:

```
real = Regex(r"\d+\.\d+").setName("real number")
lat_long = "(" + Char("NS") + real("latitude") + "," + Char("EW") + real("longitude") + ")"
```

Comment: Alright! That makes sense. I was using the simplified form of `setResultsName`. So I am guessing that when setting the name, we are not setting the result name. So if I want to have a result name and a name I must use `.setName("Expr_1").setResultsName("Expr_1")` or perhaps the shorter form `.setName("Expr_1")("Expr_1")`, correct?

Comment: That is correct. The name you set using `setName` will appear in parse exceptions and in the diagram. The name you set using `setResultsName` (or the short form) will appear in the parsed results, and is not always the same name (and I am working with TMiguelT to show the results name in the diagram also). Just like you don't name a Python list variable `list`. The results name is analogous to the variable name, and the expression name (the `setName` name) is analogous to the variable type name.